# Which auxiliary verb to use to make perfect tense of ‘erfahren’?

Tags: verb, perfect-tense

I have found contradicting suggestions for the auxiliary verb to use make the perfect tense of *erfahren*.

[Collins Dictionary (Online)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/conjugation/erfahren) suggests

> sein

while [de.wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erfahren) suggests

> haben

Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both the meanings *to experience something* and *to get told something,* *erfahren* is used only with *haben* in the perfect tense. Unlike other verbs like *stehen,* this is the same throughout the German-speaking countries.

> Ich habe gestern erfahren, dass ich heute Dienst habe.
>
> Gestern habe ich die Wirkung einer Absage erfahren.

However, there is also the closely related expression *erfahren sein,* wherein I would consider *erfahren* to be an adjectivised present participle rather than a verb. In this expression, *erfahren sein* means *to be experienced.* As *sein* is the full verb here, an phrase such as ‘Ich bin erfahren.’ is actually in present tense and can be transformed into both preterite, perfect and pluperfect separately:

> Im Umgang mit dieser Maschine **bin** ich erfahren.
>
> Er **ist** im Umgang mit Maschinen sehr erfahren **gewesen.**

Note that using this expression in the past when referring to a person typically means they passed away — although it could also mean that they’re suffering from severe amnesia or emigrated to Far Far Away.